# MetaMask doesn't support synchronous methods like eth_sendTransaction

Tags: contract-development, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

I'm trying to call a function in my smart contract and keep getting the error `Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_sendTransaction without a callback parameter` I understand that I need to make the call asynchronous but am unsure how I would do this. My code is:

```
   mainEvent.watch(function(error, result){
        if (!error)
            {
                $("#instructor").html(result.args.addr);
                console.log(result)
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
    });

   $("#button").click(function() {
       console.log(Raffle.main());
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a callback to `Raffle.main`. (I'm assuming that's the function it's complaining about.)

```
Raffle.main(function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, where abouts would I put this in my code?

Comment: It replaces the line `console.log(Raffle.main());`